# Remount as read-only the root filesystem after mount -uw /

Tags: terminal, mount, macos-catalina

I can re-mount the read-oly filesystem in catalina with:

```
sudo mount -uw /
```

I would to re-mount it as read-only after I've done what I need.
I'v tried with:

```
sudo mount -ur /
```

and

```
sudo mount -u  -o,rdonly /
```

but no luck.
So the question is: how can I restore the read-only filesystem without reboot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Ask Different

Comment: @ScottHunter reportered you to moderators.

Comment: Good for you; wouldn't want someone trying to steer people's questions to forums more appropriate to answering them.

Comment: @ScottHunter, "closing" is not "moving". Know the difference?

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood the "belongs on a different site" explanation for CLOSING; I'll look for the MOVING button next time.  Thanks for the education!

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to make a filesystem read-only without the restart.

However after the reboot filesystem should be back to read-only mode.

If that doesn't work try executing your commands from recovery mode.

- Restart OS with <kbd>CMD+R</kbd>
- Open terminal and execute your commands

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I asked "how can I restore the read-only filesystem without reboot?”

Comment: @Mike97 you are right didn't spot it was hidden in the plain sight, nevertheless hope it helps someone in the future with similar question, I edit my answers